# Apache CXF installation options into Tomcat

Tags: cxf

I want to be able to use Apache CXF with Tomcat. I have copied CXF's jar files into WEB-INF/lib and then I am able deploy my WAR file into Tomcat. That WAR file works fine in Tomcat, but that WAR file is then not usable in [IBM WebSphere Liberty JEE server](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/). I want to build my WAR files, such that they are write ones run any were.

The [CXF app server configuration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/application-server-specific-configuration-guide.html) has no mention about Tomcat; the [Metro project](https://javaee.github.io/metro/) suggest that it's own jar file be copied into Tomcat's [endorsed folder](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#XML_Parsers_and_Java). Can the same be done for CXF? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice for a Tomcat deployment is to package the CXF jar files in the WAR file. It should also work as part of Tomcat's lib folder but I don't know many deployments using that.

Maybe you should take a look at [Apache Tomee](http://tomee.apache.org/) to have a combination with Tomcat and CXF?